# tmux bind shortcut to create a pane above or to the left?

Tags: tmux

Whenever I use `tmux split-window -h/v`, it creates the new split to the right/bottom, respectively.  I want a command that creates the new split on the *other* side (i.e., to the left/top), but I can't find any simple answer for this anywhere... How can I bind this behavior into a shortcut?

What happens by default:

```
 _______                         _______
|       |                       |   |   |
|   *   | == split-window -h => |   | * |
|       |                       |   |   |
 -------                         -------
```

What I want a shortcut for:

```
 _______                         _______
|       |                       |   |   |
|   *   | ==        ?        => | * |   |
|       |                       |   |   |
 -------                         -------
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [from version **2.0**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES), tmux's `split-window` and `join-window` understand **`-b`** to create the pane to the left or above the target pane.

Split horizontally and place at the left:

```
tmux split-window -hb
```

Split vertically and place at the top:

```
tmux split-window -vb
```

**Update:**

From inside `tmux` you can use **`}`** for swapping the panels once you have split the window:

Example for vertical splitting:

```
Ctrl + B + %
Ctrl + B + }
```

Comment: This command doesn't work on my tmux (Version 1.8). Is there a way to do it in that version?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I updated the answer in order to reflect the version it is valid for. I chose to not delete it because it may help other people.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my tmux so it now answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

As above, but remember, tmux has a problem if you run it from PuTTY or from virtual machine. It works properly, but there's sometimes a problem with create, switching and resize panes due to lack of keys recognition.